Accessing Terraform Data Sources with CDK during run- not synthesis time
A Terraform project requires providers to be known upfront in a static manner; that is, I cannot use dynamic content like a Terraform data source to determine the number and configuration of providers.
I have been facing this issue for some time now, especially because I need to deploy and manage resources in Azure Subscriptions that are not known upfront. My workaround has been to use the Terraform CDK, generating the provider blocks using a general-purpose programming language.
While the CDK approach worked, I am now in a situation where the provider information could be derived from a Terraform data source. From my perspective, I have two options:

Reinvent the wheel by implementing the data retrieval already present in some Terraform provider’s data source within my CDK code.
(Somehow) access a Terraform data source from my CDK code to use for Terraform resource generation.

As I would obviously prefer the second option, do you have any idea if it’s possible to do this in a clean way (i.e., without something like deploying HCL code into a temporary directory and running Terraform)?
